# Python Selenium : access child elements with XPath locators

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I would like to access the `<p>Comment</p>` element and both `<a href>` elements from the `<div class='xyz'>` element.

Here's the structure:

```html
<div class='xyz'>
   <div>
      <h2>
      <div>
         <p>Comment</p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <buttons>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href='link 1'>Name 1</a>
            <li>
               <a href='link 2'>Name 2</a>
         </ul>
      </buttons>
   </div>
</div>
```

My code so far with missing parts `"..."`:

```py
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='xyz']")
for elem in elems:
   comment = elem.find_element_by_xpath("...")  # Comment
   print(comment.get_attribute("text"))
   files = elem.find_elements_by_xpath("...")  # link 1 and link 2
   for file in files:
      print(file.get_attribute("text")) # Name 1 then Name 2
      file.click()
```

I tried several XPath locators to access the children, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comment you can search by p element where text length is more than 0.
For this purpose it's better to create filter function, but also can be done by xpath `//p[string-length(text()) > 0]`.

For files variable seemed like css selector `buttons a` is quite unique.

```py
comment = elem.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[string-length(text()) > 0]')
files = elem.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'buttons a')
```

Comment: Thanks! There's a missing dot to only consider the children. It should read `comment = elem.find_element(By.XPATH, './/p[string-length(text()) > 0]')`.